# Append Partial to Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ok i have a site that i want a button to open this dialog box. I am trying to figure out how to append a partial to this dialog only when it is open...

there is JavaScript in that partial that errors other forms so would need to remove the partial when dialog is closed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog_box").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $("#test_button").on("click", function () {
            $("#dialog_box").dialog("open");
        });
    });
});
```

How would i be able to append a form only when the dialog opens... and remove the form when dialog closes?

```
<script>
    $('#form_div').append('<%= render(:partial => 'payment_form')%>');
</script>
```

Also i would have to have access to the instance variables from the main page.

```
@company, @user, @info
```

Page Html

```
<button id="test_button">Push Me</button>
<div class="main">
    <div id="dialog_box" title="Payment Details">
        <div id="form_div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use Dialog callback methods to control Dialog states:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog_box").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log('Dialog opened');
            },
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log('Dialog closed');
            }
        });
        $("#test_button").on("click", function () {
            $("#dialog_box").dialog("open");
        });
    });
});
```

You can find full list o methods and callbacks here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Cheers!